# Call a web service in java application from main method

Tags: java, rest, web-services, web, jersey

I am using Tom Cat server and Jersey Framework to implement a  RESTful web service. I have a main method, and I want to call this in main, and run the Tomcat. How can I do that?

```
@GET
    @Path("/{parameterPk}/{parameterData}")
    public Response getJSONObj(@PathParam("parameterPk") String parameterPk,

            @PathParam("parameterData") String parameterData) {
        System.out.println("Starting...");

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        jsonObj.put(IDENTIFIER_JSON_ID, parameterPk);
        jsonObj.put(IDENTIFIER_JSON_DATA, parameterData);

        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray();
        jsonarray.add(jsonObj);
        System.out.println(jsonarray);

        JSONObject jsonMain = new JSONObject();
        jsonMain.put("Employee", jsonarray);
        System.out.println(jsonMain.toString());

        return Response.status(200).entity(jsonMain.toString()).build();
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the service running and tested? As far I understood - you want to create a client? I believe you will get a lost of examples just searching for "java restful client" in your favouring search engine (e.g. https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-apache-httpclient-restful-client-examples)

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop a REST client to call the REST Services.

Define an URL like this in your main () method :

```
http://localhost:9080/"Context-root name"/"url-pattern"/"Path"/
```

localhost can be replaced by the IP address of the server in which the application is running.
Give the correct port no of the server where the application is running.
Find the context-Root name and put it in proper place.
Then check the URL pattern defined in your web.xml like for example "/rest/*"

```
<servlet-mapping> 
  <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name> 
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

And then give the X-Path which is defined in the class where the REST service is written.

And the by this way the REST services can be called from main () :

```
String inputForRest = "Test Message for REST";
RestClient client = new RestClient();
Resource resource = client.resource(restURL);
String responseStr = resource.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).accept("*/*").post(String.class, inputForRest);
```

Media type can be different depending upon the rest consumer like JSON, XML etc.